# How to determine form id match in form alter?

Tags: 8

In Drupal 8, I want to alter taxonomy vocab and term add/edit forms. Vocab is easy enough, but the form id for term forms seems to have this pattern:

taxonomy_term_(vocab name)_form

What can I reference to know that the form being altered is a taxonomy term add/edit form?

I tried using hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_form_alter, but that stopped working unless I implemented hook_form_alter() elsewhere in my module.

Comment: I think it is possible to check `$form['vid']['#value']` and load the vocabulary from there. Though caching might help with performance.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct hook name? It is [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Form!form.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/8), not `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_form_alter()`. (You wrote *form* twice.)

Comment: Yes, function name tvi_form_taxonomy_term_form_alter() - it gets called IF tvi_form_alter is present in the module. If I comment out tvi_form_alter, the hook is no longer called... After clearing the cache, the hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter function is hit again... I guess it was caching. Odd.

Comment: hook_form_alter, hook_form_FORM_ID_alter and hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter are totally separate things so if your form id alter hook was not working it's not because of missing hook form alter but most likely cache or mismatched form id.